# JavaScript formatting in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I want:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
       //do some
}
```

but after formatting I get:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

}
```

how can I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Tools -> Options
- Text Editor -> JScript -> Formatting
- Place open brace on new line for control blocks

[image: Visual Studio Options Dialog]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not what you want, but I suggest keeping it as is.

It is also recommended by the [Google Javascript Style Formatting Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml)

Answer (score 0):

In the menu:

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JScript -> Formatting -> New Lines

However, I agree with epoch - it's probably better to just follow the style guide.